# Trying to upload file, php, and getting an empty array

Tags: php

I have server A that this code works on and when transferring to server B the code does not work.

I am trying to upload a file using PHP and once I hit submit the $_FILES array is empty. I can see the file being sent the through $_POST array, but nothing in the $_FILES array. I am pulling my hair out and cannot find an answer. What would be the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you have not a enctype definition.

if in your html form yo have:

```
<form method="post" action="file.php">
```

change for:

```
<form method="post" action="file.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Other pronlem, has be the upload_max_filesize in your php.ini, check that, or try:

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize','512M');
```

Comment: I looked at both of these right off the bat. Enctype is setup correctly and max_filesize is set to 5M.

Comment: check any error browser side using a tool how 
Firebug -> network, or similar. ¿some especial server configuration?